# Viewing all accounts in list form

Tags: c#, database, list

A new customer should be able to:

1. Login
2. View all their Accounts in list form, without supplying Acct Nos.

[P http://puu.sh/hiYKZ/01e0da1578.png](http://puu.sh/hiYKZ/01e0da1578.png)

Here is the database, the `AcctNo` should all print out on the last form in the document, 
Question is, I've tried writing the code with the `AccountList`, yet it is not pulling up the information?

Welcome Customer input your CID:

```
public partial class WelcomeCust : Form 
{
    OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public WelcomeCust()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\ChattBankMDB.mdb";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db.Open();
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select Cid From Accounts", db);
    }
}
```

Once the Cid is entered(Customer ID) the `AcctNo` should all list itself with it.

AccountsList:

```
class AccountList : Accounts
{
    private static List<Accounts> custAccounts = new List<Accounts>();
    private String userID = "";

    public AccountList() {
    }

    public AccountList(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return this.userID;
    }

    public List<Accounts> getCustAccounts () {
        return custAccounts;
    }

    public void clearAccounts() {
       custAccounts.Clear(); 
    }

}
```

Here is the Account least in case its needed for the problem:

```
class Accounts
{
    private String acctNo;
    private String custId;
    private String type;
    private double balance;
    private String message;

    /**
     * No-Arg Constructor
     */

    /**
    *sets account number 
    *@param acctNo
    */
    public void setAcctNo(String acctNo) {
        this.acctNo = acctNo;
    }

    /**
     *sets customer id
     * @param custId
     */
    public void setCustId(String custId) {
        this.custId = custId;
    }

    /**
     * sets account type 
     * @param acctType
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * sets balance for the account
     * @param balance
     */
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    /**
     * returns account number
     * @return String
     */
    public String getAcctNo() {
        return acctNo;
    }

    /**
     * returns customer id
     * @return String
     */
    public String getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }

    /**
     * returns account type
     * @return String
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * returns account balance
     * @return double
     */
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
     * returns account information into string form
     * @return String 
     */
    public String getAcct() {
        return this.acctNo + " " + this.custId + " " + this.type + " " + this.balance;
    }

    /**
     * returns message set by other methods in class
     * @return String
     */
    public String getMessage(){
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

And finally:

Here is the form everything should print out on the listbox1.

```
public partial class AllAccounts : Form 
{
    public AllAccounts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code to load the data or bind it to a list.....?

Comment: I thought Listbox in visual studios was it.. Sorry I am new to C# with java, you have to build it yourself, but I don't quite see it on c#..

Comment: You need to use DataSource property of ListBox control at load event AllAccounts_Load.